# Remove parentheses within a sentence and separate the string

Tags: java, string

So.. if I got a string such as:

```
(P=>Q) ^ (L ^ M => P) ^ A
```

or

```
((~B V P) V M) ^ (B V ~P) ^ (B V ~M)
```

How can I remove these parentheses and keep the substrings I wish in the form:

```
P=>Q, L^M=>P, A
```

and

```
~BVPVM, BV~P, BV~M
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're writing a parser for logical formulas. Here's what I'd do:

- Define a formal grammar for your formulas and generate a parser using a tool such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).
- Parse the string using your generated parser and construct a tree-based data structure to represent these formulas.
- Traverse the tree and print the string as desired. In your case that means changing the conjunctions into commas and leaving everything else unchanged.

Comment: what I want actually to store each string and use them for further inference.. Your method sounds smart but kind of ..much effort.b

Comment: You can store the strings for further inference as well, that's not a problem. If you wish to reason about the formulas you need to break them up into their individual components anyway. A logical formula is a tree structure so that part you'll need to do anyway. The grammar/parser part can be done manually as well but a parser generator will often be easier.

Comment: And.. in this case.. what's the formal grammar?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "((~B V P) V M) ^ (B V ~P) ^ (B V ~M)";
    String result = input.replaceAll("[ ()]", "")
                         .replaceAll("\\^", ", ");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

> ~BVPVM, BV~P, BV~M

I'm sure someone will come up with some super awesome regex. In the meantime, this will suffice.

Comment: Anyway first case in OP question is good example of why regex is not good tool for this task.